# problem in selection color in select items css, i've tried several events and different forms of google

Tags: css

[image]

I'm not able to change the color at the time of selection, does anyone know how? I think this blue color is browser standard

```
.card .auth form .form-control select {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgb(22, 24, 25);
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card .auth form .form-control select:focus, .card .auth form .form-control select:valid {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 208, 0);
}

.card .auth form .form-control select option:checked {
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: .card .auth form .form-control select {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgb(22, 24, 25);
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card .auth form .form-control select:focus, .card .auth form .form-control select:valid {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 208, 0);
}

.card .auth form .form-control select option:checked {
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
   select option:focus,
    select option:active {
        background: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
        background-color: #000000 !important; /* for IE */
        color: #ffed00 !important;
    }

    select option:checked {
        background: linear-gradient(red, red);
        background-color: red !important; /* for IE */
        color: #000000 !important;
    }
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Apples</option>
  <option>Oranges</option>
  <option>Banannas</option>
</select>
```